# Request/Response using streams

Tags: c#, functional-programming, system.reactive

I have an input stream from an RS-232 port and a queue of commands to the serial port using Rx streams. I have simplified my code as follows:

```
void Init()
{
    SerialPort srl;

    ... // open serial port

    IObservable<string> obInput =
        Observable.FromEventPattern<
        SerialDataReceivedEventHandler,
        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>
        (
            handler => srl.DataReceived += handler,
            handler => srl.DataReceived -= handler
        ).SelectMany(_ =>
        {
        List<string> ret;
        ... //extract messages
        return ret;
        }).Publish().Refcount();

    obCommandOk =
        obInput
        .Where(msg => msg == "OK" || msg == "KO");

    var sAction = new Subject<string>();
    var sCommandOk = new Subject<Tuple<string,bool>>();

    sAction
        .Do(srl.WriteLine)
        .Zip(obCommandOk, (cmd, result) =>
        {
        if (result == "OK")
            sCommandOk.OnNext(Tuple.Create(cmd, true))
        else
            sCommandOk.OnNext(Tuple.Create(cmd, false))
        });
}

async bool Command(string cmd)
{
    sAction.OnNext(cmd);

    return
        await sCommandOk
        .Where(t => t.Item1 == cmd)
        .Select(t => t.Item2)
        .FirstAsync();
}
```

Sometimes happens that after OnNext the result has been already pushed to sCommandOk and so I lose it.

Can you suggest me a better approach to avoid losing responses?

Comment: Can we aim to provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please? sure I get it is psuedo code, but it is about 5 changes away from being real C# that compiles.

Comment: @LeeCampbell it is quite difficult to extrapolate what you request from my code, but I have written something that compiles here https://gist.github.com/zpul/b7a59e559e523a8a3b1077b1ec8013ef (too big for SO)

Comment: You really should not be using an external mutable buffer from `SelectMany`, that is a really really bad idea.  You will be able to guarantee absolutely nothing about its contents.

Comment: @TheInnerLight what should be used in its place?

Comment: You need to aggregate the stream data without using external mutability.  I'd recommend looking at this function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229432(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition in your `Command` method.
You push the Action, then subscribe to the result. 
If the result is quick, then you loose it.

a small change here can mitigate that:

```
async Task<bool> Command(string cmd)
{
    var result = sCommandOk
        .Where(t => t.Item1 == cmd)
        .Select(t => t.Item2)
        .FirstAsync();

    sAction.OnNext(cmd);

    return await result;
}
```

I think you can further optimise by removing the `sCommandOk` subject all together

```
async Task<bool> Command(string cmd)
{
    var result = obInput
        .Where(t => t.Item1 == cmd)
        .Select(t => t.Item2)
        .FirstAsync();

    sAction.OnNext(cmd);

    return await result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that approach and the problem persists. The only solution I've found to this time is to pass together with the command a result variable that if after the OnNext has been set, I already have the result otherwise I await. It is a very bad one so I do not like it.